# Lottery calls on municipal bonds

Tags: fixed-income, embedded-options

I'm trying to independently price several municipal bonds with lottery calls. Based on market prices/yields I can tell that the price, ytw, etc. is not based upon the first viable call. What is the standard for lottery calls? Is each call simply probability weighted by the amount due for redemption upon that call date? Additionally, the data in Bloomberg is a bit inconsistent. If these bonds have mandatory partial redemptions sometimes it looks like the mandatory redemptions are reflected in the sink schedules; is it safe to assume that the sinks are one to one with the calls? Thanks in advance for any responses.